# What is the maximum speed of an object moving trough air?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

While seeing the comic [Flash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_(comics)) I wondered what could be the maximum speed of a invulnerable human being (like Allen) running through air on the surface of the Earth? At what speed would its surrounding material ignite?

**Sidenote: it's a thought experiment**

For logical reasoning one could replace the human being by a object of similar size made out of a highly heat resistant material like [LI-900](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LI-900) accelerated constantly by a centrifuge in a controlled environment. The question would be: what is the speed at which the centrifuge* can't accelerate the object anymore? Is there such a limit?

You can make assumptions on the experiment to ease the calculation.

<sub>*: let's say the centrifuge has a tremendous amount of energy at its disposal to be powered</sub>

Comment: How shall an immutable human run?

Comment: [From Worldbuilding.](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/20706/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking us to diagnose a fictional event.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos If you will you could replace the human being as a very resistant object of similar size made out of carbon fiber or even heat shield material.

Comment: @SebastianRiese: it's indeed fictional but can easily being replace by a non-fictional object like I said herein above.

Answer (score 2):

An interesting limitation aside from the obvious practical ones being overlooked, is that eventually you would be moving quickly enough to bond your carbon atoms with oxygen in the air. If we put a lower limit of around 750 degrees F or about 673 Kelvin to start that fire, then you would have to move at about 1,300 meters per second.

Comment: +1 In principle I think this is right: you've simply set $m\,v^2 \approx k\,T$ for $T=673{\rm K}$, right? But I'm not sure that it's equivalent to kindling because I'm guessing oxidized material would be stripped of the surface and wouldn't the kindling chain reaction wouldn't spread. I'm guessing this would lead to faster ablation and erosion and it would be slower than setting fire to something. Do you know what happens to flammable things in hypersonic wind tunnels at this speed (I don't - you might like to say more about this)?

Comment: No I don't know much about that but it is a very interesting question. Maybe some who reads your comment can elaborate for us.

Comment: I only say this because I know flames cannot survive flows: one of the tragedies of the 2000 Concorde accident was that the fire was probably not life threatening at all: if the copilot wouldn't have shut the engine concerned down, the flames would have been swiftly quenched by the higher speed flow the aircraft would have reached with its full thrust mostly intact. One of many mistakes made, all of which were needed to lead the the accident.

Comment: There are guns that shoot faster than this, so it seems like a pretty low limit.

Comment: @ChrisWhite I thought this was pretty low too. And I thought about guns too, until I recalled that guns don't generally shoot flammable stuff. I'm guessing the effect would be an oxidation-enhanced erosion - it would be good to hear from someone who knows what happens to flammable things in hypersonic wind tunnels.

Comment: Wasn't the Chelyabinsk meteor traveling at about 100k kmh?